# How do I get Google Now to report correct season-related information?

Tags: google, geolocation, google-voice-actions

At time of writing, it's mid-summer (July 27, USA). On my Galaxy S7, when I activate Google voice search and ask it how many days until fall, it tells me 217 days, which I know is wrong.  When I ask it how many days until winter, it says winter started 56 days ago.

Does it think I am in Australia or something?  How do I fix this?

Note:  My Google search region is set to United States and my location is set correctly.

Comment: [It seems to be a bug, not yet fixed](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/news/I4kn56HYILk/QWdODx7fAAAJ)

Comment: @beeshyams Well that's a shame.  Can you tell me where you found that information?  I'd like to look into it more myself.

Comment: Click the link above ! That's why linked it. And if you want that as an answer let me know

Comment: @beeshyams *facepalm* DOH!  I didn't even realize that.  Sorry!  Thanks!

Comment: It basically talks about Google news, but in the same thread you find referred to Google weather too. And it's dated a month ago

Comment: I just wanted to add here that it turns out this problem isn't related to my mobile device.  It seems to be a Google-side issue because I get the same result on multiple devices, including desktop PC in multiple browsers.  I hope it gets fixed soon.